# Azure Front-Door Route to API-M returns "DNSNameNotResolved" ErrorInfo

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door

Randomly without any warning a request to be routed to a backend process returns a 503 error. After looking into it it looks like a "DNSNameNotResolved" get returned when forwarding the request.
I tried looking around but could not find out why this happens. The appears to be no problems when routing to the backend. I also can't find the request on the Backend at all. The backend is an Azure API-M service.

Answer (score 0):

> When one machine has to connect to another machine, it has to perform
> DNS name resolution.

The  Error indicates that APIM wasn't able to convert the hostname of the backend (e.g. contoso.azurewebsites.com) to an IP address and couldn't connect to it.
The most frequent cause for this error is using an incorrect hostname while setting up the API configuration

- **Refer the common network configuration issues on APIM**
  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-common-network-configuration-issues
- **You may try by DNS resolution  by refering** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway#set-up-custom-domain-names-in-api-management
- **Along with the DNS configuration**
  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain#dns-configuration
- **Also check if the Public IP address of APIM service is unchanged**
  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ip-addresses#changes-to-the-ip-addresses

Other References:

- Tutorial to add custom domain to your front door-
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain
- Troubleshoot Azure Front Door configuration problems- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-troubleshoot-routing

Comment: Thanks, i haven't picked up on any IP changes at API-M, i'll have to take a look at the logs if this could be it. But other than that everything has been working until recently that randomly one of the requests get a 503 Response with the "DNSNameNotResolved". It's sad the new front-door changes that might solve out problem are still in preview.
We have a custom DNS also running on both and thats not causing any issues. It's the default DNS the resource comes with that is.

Answer (score 0):

So according to Microsoft, the TTL on the DNS records on Front-Door is really short and thus it is very DNS aggressive, this falls within the 99.9% uptime. When this falls within the said uptime they will look into adjustments for Front-Door.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).